# not getting String from Listview OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, onitemclicklistener

I am displaying names from my database in a ListView; which is working fine. I want to implement a function of an onclicklistener that passes that string to another activity. I can get it somewhat working but it only passes andoid.database.sqlite...
Below is my code where I try an OnItemClickLIstener to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private MyExercisesDB myExerciseDB;
private ListView myExerciseList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_exe);

    myExerciseList = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.custExerLV);

    openDB();
    populateLVFromDB();
    myExerciseList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) 
        {
            String selectedFromList = myExerciseList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            GlobalVars.setVar(selectedFromList);
            startActivity(new Intent(CustomExeActivity.this, AddToCalendar.class));
        }

    });
```

Comment: I found the answer to my problem. I needed to have this code where my cursor was initialized and set it there like this: myExerciseList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
  {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) 
   {
    c.moveToPosition(position); 
    String exerciseName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title"));
    GlobalVars.setVar(exerciseName);
    startActivity(new Intent(CustomExeActivity.this, AddToCalendar.class));
   }
   
  });

Comment: You can get the cursor from the `AdapterView` too in `onItemClick()`: `Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)`. The advantage is that you don't need to keep a hard reference to the cursor and it will already be positioned to point to the clicked item.